# addLoadEvent can't work?

Tags: javascript, html

guys.I was confused by a easy problem.Please help me.Why my function addLoadEvent can't upload some js files at the same time?
  This is my code:

```
function addLoadEvent(func) {
    var oldonload = window.onload;
    if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
        window.onload = func;   
    }else{
        window.onload = function() {
            oldonload;
            func();
        }
    }
}
```

and:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" media="screen" href="styles/typography.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/addLoadEvent.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/displayCitations.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/displayAccessKeys.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/displayAbbreviations.js">
</script>
```

Why my function addLoadEvent always upload the last one JavaSript file,and other two file was coverd?

Comment: what does addLoadEvent.js do?

Answer (score 1):

You're not calling `oldonload`.

```
window.onload = function() {
    oldonload(); // <-- need () there
    func();
}
```

Consider using `addEventListener`.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is really not the right way to have multiple event handlers.  Instead, just use `window.addEventListener()` since the capability to have multiple event handlers is already built-in and there is no reason to re-invent it.

```
function addLoadEvent(func) {
    window.addEventListener("load", func);
}
```

Comment: I just learn this JavaScript at a short time,and I would see your function,thankyou!